# How do I put a BLOB in root, not $root?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to use the `WindowsAzure.Storage` C# NuGet package to upload a BLOB to the *root* of a container. If I do the following:

```
var AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING_TEMPLATE = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1};BlobEndpoint={2};";
var string AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "devstoreaccount1";
var string AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY = "abcd-redacted";
var string AZURE_BLOB_ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devaccount1/mycontainer";

var azureBlobConnectionString = string.Format(
  AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING_TEMPLATE,
  AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
  AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY,
  AZURE_BLOB_ENDPOINT);

var container = serviceClient.GetRootContainerReference();
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(Path.GetFileName(FILE_TO_UPLOAD));
```

The BLOB ends up in a container called `$root`, and it doesn't actually show in the "root" of the container. If I try the following:

```
var container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("/");
```

It ends up in a container called `<no name>`.

I want the file to be in the root of the container called `mycontainer`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you are getting confused here between the *root container* and the *root directory of a container*.  `$root` is a special container that is referenced by `https://yourazureaccount/someiteminroot`.  if you want an item in the root directory of a container, it would be `https://yourazureaccount/somecontainer/someiteminroot`.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/working-with-the-root-container.

Comment: I'm aware there is a difference between *root container* and *root directory*. I'm wanting to know how I can use the C# `WindowsAzure.Storage` library to add a BLOB to the root *directory*.

Comment: the root directory *of what*?  blobs must exist in a container, and if you are comparing containers to directories, every sub directory is another container.....  you either specify the container by name in the URL, or you specify the blob only and will find it in `$root`.

Comment: Edited for clarity: I want the file in the root of the container called "mycontainer".

Comment: then does `var container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");` not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the specified container in the GetContainerReference() method:

Code like below:

```
  string StorageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=your_account;AccountKey=your_key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageConnectionString);
  var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
  var container = client.GetContainerReference("t11");
  var cloudBlockBlob =  container.GetBlockBlobReference(@"test1234.txt");
  cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(@"d:\test1234.txt");
```

it would uploaded your file to your specified container.

Comment: Could you put that in terms of my example? I.e. not using appsettings.

Comment: you can just put the connection string in code, then remove appsettings in config file. Code updated.

Comment: I'm seeing that what's different is my connection string includes `BlobEndpoint`, but yours doesn't. In my case, that parameter refers to the full URL, including container, which means the `CloudBlobClient` is already "scoped" to that container, which made it impossible to get to the root directory of the container. If I excluded that parameter from the connection string, a call to `client.GetContainerReference("mycontainer")` would actually get a "root" reference like I was after.